# Load existing GameObjects into a 2D array

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a tile based board game (on a grid). In going about making the gameboard, the easy thing would be to instantiate all of the tiles in code, but then they only appear in play mode. I want to be able to edit the tiles in the editor, but I still want my tiles to be stored in a 2D array in my controller class. If I build the board in the editor, how might I go about loading them in at runtime?

Comment: In your controller class, you can declare a public "double" array of GameObjects, and then, drag & drop your tiles through the inspector. In fact, you will have to create a serializable struct/class containing a 1D array of GameObjects (you can call "RowTiles"), and, in your controller, declare a public 1D array of `RowTiles`

Comment: @Hellium what if I spawn the tiles in an editor script (there are going to be a lot of tiles, I don't want to create and position them one at a time). Do you know how I might spawn them and add them to that array in my editor script?

Comment: @Hellium Whoah, you lost me after you edited your comment. Could you post a code snippet demonstrating what you're talking about in an answer?

Comment: I guess you can call something like `GameObject.FindObjectOfType` to get the controller after you have instantiated your tiles, and then, fill the "fake" 2D array.

Comment: @Hellium oh, I know what I can do. If the editor script's target is the `BoardController` then I can store them directly when I'm instantiating them.

Answer (score 0):

Keep The Tiles in the Resources Folder Unity. At Run-time Load from the Resources and instantiate Tiles To Your Grid Positions in the Scene.

```
GameObject[] Tiles= (Resources.LoadAll<GameObject> ("Tiles"));
```